# Creating a secure 'view email in browser' link for html emails

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

My PHP codeigniter site sends 3 types of emails to users, they are html formatted and I wish to have a 'view this email in browser' link option.

How can I create a reasonably secure link? 2 of the emails are sensitive in nature:

1. New Registration: email shows their details and an activation link
2. Forgot Pass: email shows the link to reset pass

Is it enough to just do something like this?:

```
$code = sha1(mt_rand(10000,99999).time().$user_email);

$link = 'email/view/' . $code . '/' . $user_id . '/';

        => http://mysite.com/email/view/c0acc09c6d00b706e1e511e52f286b1859067047/213/
```

So authentication would be done based on a random hash and their user_id. Is it worth hashing the user id also?

Comment: I think you are talking about 2 different things.  1) How to display an email in the browser (an option I've never seen) and 2) How to provide a URL in an email which will authenticate the user.  I think the latter is the one you're really trying to achieve, am I right?

Comment: Use `mt_rand()` without any arguments. That will give you billions of possible numbers instead of just 99999. You could also get more unpredictable hashes by using `microtime()` instead of `time()`. It's all about increasing the number of possible hashes.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the hash to sha1(mt_rand().microtime().$user_email));

Comment: you don't need to roll your own unique id with rand, php has a function for that: uniqid()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't include the user_id as a URL parameter, I'd just stick with the hash.

As soon as somebody navigates to the link, the hash should be cross-checked with those stored in your database, and if they match, pull the information associated with that e-mail (i.e. username, e-mail).  When they go to fill out the form you can validate to see if their entered data is compatible.

For example, if a user has forgotten their password, as soon as they enter their e-mail address I reset their password to a random value (stored as a hash) and use this stored hash as the URL parameter in their reset e-mail.

Comment: Thx, I was thinking the user id guarantees it will be unique? though since I'm using the email in the hash, there should be no collision (email must be unique at registration time).

Comment: Yeah, I'd just use `md5(time().$user_id)`. If you're worried about the freakishly slim chance that the hash will be the same as another, you can use `microtime()` instead of `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine, I'd add that once the sensitive pages have been viewed, it'd be a good job to remove those pages from working with that hash a second time - when you send the email have the hash stored in the db, and when the page is viewed check the hash exists, if so allow the page view, and remove the hash from the db so it would fail the check if the page is viewed a second time. (assuming they wont ever need to view the same link twice from that email).

Comment: Thx, I would remove them after 1 view in the case of password-reset. Not sure re: the others though an expiry date might be good.

Comment: If something will be viewed more than once - it's probably best to have them log in first before they can view it if it's really that sensitive.